# Small program having some looping issues

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while, infinite

Just having a small issue with a small program that i'm doing for my entry level programming course.

This loop is infinitely repeating and I can't seem to figure out why. I'm suspecting that the while loop within the do loop has some kind of conflict and that's causing the loop to repeat continuously.
Here is the code:
    import java.util.*;

public class secretAnswer

{

```
public static void main(String [ ]  args)
{
    final char answer = ('r');
    String input;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    do
    {
    System.out.println("What is your guess?");
    input = sc.next();
    while(!input.equals("stop")) //If the user doesn't want to stop, continue
    {
        if(input.contains(""+answer)) //If the input contains the answer, print the following statement
        {
            System.out.println("Your input contained the secret letter");
        }
        else //If the input doesn't contain the answer, print the following statement
        {
            System.out.println("Your input does not contain the secret letter");
        }

    }
    }

    while(!input.equals("stop")); //loop the program if the input is not equal to 'stop'
}
```

}

Comment: You should try to format it a little nicer so the indentations line up.  It makes for easier readability and can sometimes help solve the problem.

Comment: Also, why do you have a while loop inside with the same condition as your do-while loop?  You should get rid of the nested while loop.

Comment: I always seem to have issues with my formatting when I paste it to this website. I think it might be an issue with my browser. Regardless, it was another stupid error on my behalf. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: no problem, we're here to help!

Answer (score 4):

Because you need to ask the user again to input new `guess`, you just take the input once from the user , if equal `stop` will end the program if not will loop forever  , So try this :

```
  while (!input.equals("stop")) //If the user doesn't want to stop, continue
            {

                if (input.contains("" + answer)) //If the input contains the answer, print the following statement
                {
                    System.out.println("Your input contained the secret letter");
                } else //If the input doesn't contain the answer, print the following statement
                {
                    System.out.println("Your input does not contain the secret letter");
                }
                System.out.println("What is your guess?");
                input = sc.next();///////////////here the user will enter the new guess

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for two loops. The outer Do..while loop is sufficient. The DO loop executes once, then again scans new token, then based on this it will decide its next iteration.

But, at first if you don't enter "stop" from the keyboard, the condition of inside loop is going to be true.

There are two options:

1. Either you add another

   ```
   input = sc.next();
   ```

   in the inside while loop, so that there is a chance for the condition to be False and exit from the loop.
2. Or you remove the inside loop completely. Keep only the outside while loop, it will keep iterating as you go on entering strings from the console, and stop when you type

   ```
   "stop"
   ```

   .

I would have done chosen the second option. Although, in first option, to stop two loops, you have to type STOP twice, once for inside loop and once for outside loop.

Just indent and edit your code nicely, don't use spaces when you indent on the next line, use tabs, it makes code elegant.

You can use the code given by the man who's answer is above my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are unnecessarily using a while loop inside do loop
it should be a if statement and everything will work as you wanted

```
do
    {
    System.out.println("What is your guess?");
    input = sc.next();
    System.out.println("input" + input);
    if(!input.equals("stop")) //If the user doesn't want to stop, continue
    {
        if(input.contains(""+answer)) //If the input contains the answer, print the following statement
        {
            System.out.println("Your input contained the secret letter");
        }
        else //If the input doesn't contain the answer, print the following     statement
        {
            System.out.println("Your input does not contain the secret letter");
        }

    }
    }

    while(!input.equals("stop")); //loop the program if the input is not equal to    
 'stop'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your inner loop. You don't reassign input there!